# Dynamically created custom directive not linking ng-model to $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a dynamic custom directive which has a bidirectional ng-model, But for some reason controller cannot access the ng-model $scope binding and I tried without dynamic custom directive by hardcoding view (skipping step 1) which binds to $scope without any issue, I am not sure if i need to recompile or it is a scope issue

**Step 1:** Creates `<inputbox>` custom directive using json retrieved from the database dynamically and  compiles DOM
**Step 2:** Replaces `<inputbox> with <input
    ng-Model="ngModel">` (ngModel not binding to $scope)

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/H3q4Xb?p=preview)

Hours of troubleshooting no idea why its not binding, Any help is really appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: open the console in plunker and you will see an error

Comment: I just updated the plunker for that error (different issue) and still not linking

Comment: I managed to fix this issue temporarily by using $parent scope to ng-model and it works like magic http://plnkr.co/edit/Dm9Tqd but I am not sure why it does not link for dynamically created html without $parent scope, thanks